# Prevent Anonymous logons on windows-server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, audit, eventviewer, ntlm

I can't figure out how to entirely disable anonymous logon on Windows Server 2016 which is not a domain controller (regular instance). With the settings currently set I'm truly surprised  to see such logons come through which stands opposite to description of corresponding settings in SecPol.msc I' have turned logon auditing on.

**I have the following entries *set* in Local Policy Settings:**

Network access: Allow anonymous SID/Name translation : disable

Network access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts: Enabled

Network access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts and shares: Enabled

Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users: Disabled

Network access: Named Pipes that can be accessed anonymously: None

Network access: Shares that can be accessed anonymously: None

What's more I've completely disabled NTLMv1 by settings
"Send NTLMv2 responsly only" in secpol.msc.

Still, I'm getting the following Audit Success entries in event log:

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Information:
    Logon Type:     3
    Restricted Admin Mode:  -
    Virtual Account:        No
    Elevated Token:     No

Impersonation Level:        Impersonation

New Logon:
    Security ID:        ANONYMOUS LOGON
    Account Name:       ANONYMOUS LOGON
    Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
    Logon ID:       0xDC9CEC8
    Linked Logon ID:        0x0
    Network Account Name:   -
    Network Account Domain: -
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x0
    Process Name:       -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   -
    Source Network Address: xxxxxxx
    Source Port:        59691

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   NTLM V1
    Key Length:     0
```

Also, the following attempt failed:

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       ADMIN
    Account Domain:      

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC0000064

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x0
    Caller Process Name:    -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   \\xxxxx
    Source Network Address: xxxxxxx
    Source Port:        1339

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

Right now, I'm using automated offline log analysis to block the prior.

Any idea how to block anonymous logon entirely?